# Labels for grouped bar plot with uneven length of data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with a plot that contains an uneven length of data. I created another group of females (green bars), and I would like to label these two female groups `F1` and `F2`.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4']
labels2 = ['F1', 'F2'] 
male = [1, 3, 10, 20]
female = [2, 7]
female_2 = [3, 11]

x_male = np.arange(len(male))
x_female = np.arange(len(female))

offset_male = np.zeros(len(male))
offset_female = np.zeros(len(female))

shorter = min(len(x_male), len(x_female))

width = 0.25  # the width of the bars

offset_male[:shorter] = width/2
offset_female[:shorter] = width/2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x_male - offset_male, male, width, label='male')
rects2 = ax.bar(x_female + offset_female, female, width, label='female')
rects3 = ax.bar(x_female + 3 * offset_female, female_2, width, label='female')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_xticks(x_male)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Please explain further.  Where do you want the F labels to appear and why? It might help to know what your data and labels represent.

Comment: I would like represent another group of female by F (bars are in green). Therefore, my goal is to get ticks F1 and F2 at the middle of each green bar.

Answer (score 2):

blend all ticks together

```
ax.set_xticks(list(x_male)+list(x_female + 3 * offset_female))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels+labels2)
```

Comment: It is a great and simple solution. Thanks!